# Class from Animate CSS file is not functional

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In the below code, everything is working except for the animated css class. 
The Code in `<div class="jumbotron">` is supposed to animate by fadeInLeft class but it is not.
I checked the location of css and location is perfect, is there something I'm missing. Please help. Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <title>Admin Learn Test</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Fontawesome link -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <!-- Animate CSS -->
      <link ref="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
      <link ref="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Consiant logo" width="30px"> </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-9">Consiant</div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <!--Navbar header close -->
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="post.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="contact-us.html"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact Us</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      <div class="jumbotron" >
         <div class="container">
            <div  class="animated fadeInLeft" id="details">
               <h1>Consiant <span> Blog</span></h1>
               <p>The Blog which will make your thoughts richer.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>
      <section>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                     <!-- Indicators -->
                     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                     </ol>
                     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                           <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="...">
                           <div class="carousel-caption">
                              .TMe Coolness..
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                           <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="...">
                           <div class="carousel-caption">
                              More of the coolness
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                           <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="...">
                           <div class="carousel-caption">
                              Continuity of the coolness
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        ...
                     </div>
                     <!-- Controls -->
                     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                     </a>
                     <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Slider --> 
                  <div class="post">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 post-date">
                           <div class="day">16</div>
                           <div class="month">January</div>
                           <div class="year">2017</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 post-title">
                           <a href="">
                              <h2>Heading for post 1</h2>
                           </a>
                           <p>Written by: <span>Lekhraj Prasad</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 profile-picture">
                           <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="profile picture" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <a href="#"><img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="Lekhraj Prasad"></a>
                     <p class="desc"> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
                     <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                     <div class="bottom">
                        <span class="first"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Category</a></span> |
                        <span class="sec"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Comment</a></span>
                     </div>
                  </div> <!-- End of Post -->
                  <div class="post">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 post-date">
                           <div class="day">16</div>
                           <div class="month">January</div>
                           <div class="year">2017</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 post-title">
                           <a href="">
                              <h2>Heading for post 1</h2>
                           </a>
                           <p>Written by: <span>Lekhraj Prasad</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 profile-picture">
                           <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="profile picture" class="img-circle">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <a href="#"><img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="Lekhraj Prasad"></a>
                     <p class="desc"> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
                     <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                     <div class="bottom">
                        <span class="first"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Category</a></span> |
                        <span class="sec"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Comment</a></span>
                     </div>
                  </div> <!-- End of Post -->
                  <nav aria-label="Page navigation" id="pagination">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                       <li>
                         <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                         <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                          </a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                       <li>
                         <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                         </a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>

               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="widgets">
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button> 
                        </span>
                     </div>
                     <!-- input - group -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- widget close -->
                  <div class="widgets">
                     <div class="popular">
                        <h4>Popular Posts </h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-8 details">
                              <a href="#">
                                 <h4>Heading for Post</h4>
                              </a>
                              <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 14 December, 2017</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-8 details">
                              <a href="#">
                                 <h4>Heading for Post</h4>
                              </a>
                              <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 14 December, 2017</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-8 details">
                              <a href="#">
                                 <h4>Heading for Post</h4>
                              </a>
                              <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 14 December, 2017</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- Popular posts -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- widget close -->
                  <div class="widgets">
                     <div class="popular">
                        <h4>Recent Posts </h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-8 details">
                              <a href="#">
                                 <h4>Heading for Post</h4>
                              </a>
                              <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 14 December, 2017</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-8 details">
                              <a href="#">
                                 <h4>Heading for Post</h4>
                              </a>
                              <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 14 December, 2017</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                              <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-8 details">
                              <a href="#">
                                 <h4>Heading for Post</h4>
                              </a>
                              <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 14 December, 2017</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- Recent Posts -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- widget close -->
                  <div class="widgets">
                     <div class="popular">
                        <h4>Categories </h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <ul>
                                 <li><a href="">A</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">B</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">C</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">D</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">E</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <ul>
                                 <li><a href="">A</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">B</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">C</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">D</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="">E</a></li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- input - group -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- Category -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="widgets">
                     <div class="popular">
                        <h4>Social Icons </h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-4">
                              <a href="#"><img src="img/youtube.png" alt=""></a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-4">
                              <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-4">
                              <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt=""></a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- input - group -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- Category -->
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column md-4 ends here -->
         </div>
         <!-- row ends -->
         </div>
         <!-- container ends -->
      </section>
      <footer>
         <div class="container">
            Copyright &copy;  <a href="http://www.consiant.com"> Consiant </a> All rights reserved 2017.
         </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I reloaded the file several times and checked closely. I'm 100% sure it is not working.

Comment: Can you supply an example that actually demonstrates the issue? When I copy your code into a HTML file, all I get is 6 errors about files not found. By the way, are you really supposed to load both animate.css and animate.min.css? That sounds a bit redundant a bit.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
 I added only animate.min.css file, but after the not working problem. I ended up in adding both files, it is not working either way.  I believe all not found files are css files & js files, all those files are available in correct folder & animate css file is downloaded from this website : https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/
and untouched copied to css folder & Those js files are downloaded from bootstrap official website.